# Converting RGB to individual decimal values

Tags: colors, rgb

I have Red, Green, and Blue values being represented as decimal values.  I need to be able to convert them to a color (like a standard RGB 255, 255, 255 or HSV or HSL).

For example:

```
Red = 0.7
Green = 0.8
Blue = 0.7
```

would result in a "Green" color

```
Red = 5.00
Green = 0.50
Blue = 0.00
```

would result in a "Redish/Brown" color

I've tried to do basic conversion to RGB (0-255, 0-255, 0-255) and nothing really maps correctly given that the intensity of colors increase above a decimal value of 1.0  So I'm very puzzled on how I can convert these decimal values to match up with an RGB color chart?

The values seem to work more like a "Color mixer" ... the higher the decimal value the more "Bright/intense" the color.

For example:

```
Red = 10.0
Green = 10.0
Blue = 10.0
```

results in an off white, but

```
Red = 40.0
Green = 40.0
Blue = 40.0
```

results in a very bright white

But I can't seem to figure out how to calculate a conversion from these decimal value to a RGB standard color chart value (and visa-versa)?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I do not understand which convention are you using. The first example: for me it would never be a green, and I would not see a red-brown in the second one. As first: you should always define which values has white. Most common: 255,255,255 or 1,1,1 or 100,100,100. Sometime you have different white value on each channel (sometime you should define also the black point, not always it is 0,0,0). And there are other important stuff you should define (and we must know) in order to help. Please improve your answer (with such data, or where the data come). sRGB is common on computer screen

Comment: That's my question, I don't know have any reference point how 0.7, 0.8, 0.7 represents a green color.  I don't understand the convention either and was hoping someone could fill me in with an answer.  I can only provide you with data points and the results from those data points.  I'm looking for a formula to convert these individual decimal values into their corresponding 255,255,255 colors.

Comment: Just from that data, it is difficult/impossible. Where did you get such value? (program/book/website: that would help us). Ev. about application of that colours. In any case, you should find what it is the colour of white (is it 100, 100, 100?). What it is the level of mid-gray [what you may perceive as colour between black and white)? (18,18,18)? Possibly you values are just not scaled to 100, but to 50 or less (and maybe every image has own "white value"). Probably you need a lot of experimenting (and detective work on how the colour values were generated).

Comment: Source is attribute values from XML files from a flight simulator.  They use a decimal value indicated above R, G, B to color vegetation (trees) ... the trees are "materials" (textures).  So to make a tree/texture appear more "green" the I would increase the Green (from 0.8 to 1.5).  If I want an almost pure white tree I would set R = 50.0, G=50.0, B=50.0.  The colors operate more like Adobe's Channel Mixer but with the ability to specify very higher range of values for R, G, B.